# Salesforce Production Deployment Test Class Error out

Tags: unit-test, deployment, code-coverage, ant, production

As we all know for production deployment , Test classes will be automatically running , right !!! . We have issue with that . Half of our test classes are failing because of access issues .

**Things to note:**

1. in Our test classes it is not using any database data .ie SeeAllData =false
2. First deployment to Production . No recordtypes available
3. we are pushing admin profile in the package which have access to all the records types present.

**Issue:** Test class is using below statement for creating dummy record with specific record type

```
Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('XXXXX').getRecordTypeId();
```

**Actual Issue:** As our production doesn't have any recordtype test class is failing saying it unable to find the record type.

How can we fix this issue?

Comment: are you pushing the recordtypes as part of the deployment?

Comment: we found the solution for it . For the system admin profile, for the account record type , we need to select person account .(in our org person account is activated )

Answer (score 0):

Create a Contact recordtype `XXXXX` in Production and assign that recordtype to the Admin profile.

And rerun the test classes.

First deploy configuration related items from one package and after that deploy other components like class, pages, triggers etc.